# FFMPEG convert video to gif

Tags: android, ffmpeg, animated-gif, android-ffmpeg

I want convert video to gif with FFMPEG.

and this is my code:

```
                File gifFile=new File(file.getParentFile().getPath()+"/someee.gif");
                String[] command = {"-i", file.getPath(), gifFile.getPath()};
                FFmpeg.getInstance(getContext()).execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String message) {
                        Log.i("FFmpegggggggg:success", message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(String message) {
                        Log.i("FFmpegggggggg:onProgre", message);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String message) {
                        Log.i("FFmpegggggggg:Fail", message);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        Log.i("FFmpegggggggg:Start", "Start");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        Log.i("FFmpegggggggg:Finish", "finish");

                    }
                });
```

variable file = user choose file from gallery and I take it;
this is example for file and giftfile path:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/Comp 1.mp4
/storage/emulated/0/Download/someee.gif
```

I try two ways and both return error to me:

1 - Create someee.gif in Download directry

2 - Whitout create someee.gif in download directory

And this is my error:

```
E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: [/data/user/0/com.diacotdj.liom/files/ffmpeg, ffmpeg, -i, /storage/emulated/0/Download/Comp 1.mp4, /storage/emulated/0/Download/someee.gif]
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.diacotdj.liom/files/ffmpeg": error=2, No such file or directory
```

What can i do?

Comment: Java seems to not be able to find FFmpeg binary at `/data/user/0/com.diacotdj.liom/files/ffmpeg`, which indicates either ffmpeg is not installed or your `FFmpeg` object is not properly set up with wherever the `ffmpeg` binary is located in your system.

Comment: @kesh I just add library in gradle and use it . My phone was supported FFMPEG.
I define FFMPEG object in first line of Class . Can you explain more what can i do for install FFMPEG(except gradle)?
tnx for help

Comment: I'm neither Android nor Java dev, so I cannot comment much more than what I already did. But is [this](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) what you are using? If so, do you have `ffmpeg.loadBinary()` earlier in the app? If not, you probably need to do that. Then what's the output of executing `command = "-version"`?